# How to update document in one collection when a document of other collection is changed or updated in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I've created two collections "Users" and "Posts".

Users document structure is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54dde0e32a2a999c0f00002a"
    },
    "first_name": "Vamsi",
    "last_name": "Krishna",
    "email": "vamshi@test.com",
    "password": "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99",
    "date_of_birth": "1999-01-05",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "Active",
    "date_created": "2015-02-13 12:32:50"
}
```

While posts document structure is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54e1a2892a2a99d00500002b"
    },
    "post_description": "Test post 1",
    "posted_by": {
        "id": "54dde0e32a2a999c0f00002a",
        "first_name": "Vamsi",
        "last_name": "Krishna",
        "gender": "male"
    },
    "posted_on": "2015-02-16 08:55:53",
    "comments": [],
    "likes": {
        "count": 0,
        "liked_by": []
    }
}
```

My query is that when user updates his information it should reflect everywhere like posted by, commented by and liked by. How can I achieve that?

I'm using PHP.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not have a notion similar to sql `on update cascade`, so you have to do this in your application (whenever you update user information, update all other documents that relate to this user in other collections).

As you might have guessed this is super inefficient when there are a lot of such documents, which means that your schema is bad. Just have a `userID` in your document and this will link to your user's collection.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm trying to do it using PHP coding. How can I get user info using user id by executing single find query? However I'm storing user id in the posts collection document.